# Lie Bracket - Lie derivative: computational experiments

Tags: lie-algebras

Can anyone, with a simple and illustrative example, explain the meaning of such concepts as the Lie derivative and the Lie bracket and demonstrate a simple computational experiment for a function of 3-4 variables?
Theoretically, everything is more or less clear, but what this gives in the calculations and, most importantly, what exactly these calculations show is not clear.